# Resize dimension images BEFORE upload to server with JQuery-file-upload?

Tags: jquery, html, css, upload, jquery-file-upload

Do you know if it's possible to resize dimension (width and height) of an image BEFORE upload to server with JQuery-file-upload ?

I know you can do it with Plupload... But i was wondering if it's possible with JQuery-file-upload..

Thanks!

Comment: If you can do it with Plupload, you can do it with jQuery file uploader, as they are both just javascript plugins. However, browser resizing like that is dependant on the browser supporting certain HTML5 API's, so it's usually a better idea to do the resizing on the serverside.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a business that deal with photographers. My photographers upload around 1000 pictures every time in Hirez. I shrink them in low rez using Aurigma. But with the saga of JAVA, i need to find a simpler solution for not dealing with JAVA. That's why, i need a solution from the client side. I assume that my photographers use modern browser so..it's not a problem for that. Plupload is working great..but i prefer the look and simplicity of jQuery file uploader. Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at the [page for client side resizing](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Client-side-Image-Resizing) in the documentation for the jQuery file uploader plugin

Comment: Thank you. No. I will do that right now! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this doing it like this:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
                url: '/general/up/',
                dataType: 'json',
                acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
                disableImageResize: false,
                imageMaxWidth: 1920,
                imageMaxHeight: 1920,
                imageCrop: false,
                done: function (e, data) {
                        console.log('success');
                }
}).bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    data.imageMaxWidth = $('#up_resize_to').val();
    data.imageMaxHeight = $('#up_resize_to').val();
});
```

Comment: Welcome! I just wanted to suggest that you could try to explain a bit better your answer by adding a brief explanation of your solution together with the code.